# CLOSED - Drag and Drop in HTML - Drop Between Boxes JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, image, drag-and-drop

Greeting. I am currently working on a slideshow creator that uses the HTML5 Drag and Drop API. With these API I have been able to create a grid of user uploaded images. These images can be rearranged in any order that would you like, but only by swapping one for one. What I would like to be able to do is to be able to drop the image on top of another image, causing all images in front of it to be moved to the right.

I.E I insert a new image, and drop it on image 5. I wasnt the excisting image 5 to be moved to box 6, 6 to 7, 7 to 8, and so on and so forth. I would like to be able insert images that way, verses swapping them.. I just cant figure out how to accomplish this. Here is my code

```
   var dragSrcEl = null;
    var cols = document.querySelectorAll('#columns .column');
    [ ].forEach.call(cols, function (col) {
        col.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
        col.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false)
        col.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
        col.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
        col.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
        col.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
    });

function handleDragStart(e) {
  // Target (this) element is the source node.
  dragSrcEl = this;
  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.innerHTML);
}
function handleDragOver(e) {
  if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Necessary. Allows us to drop.
  }
  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';  // See the section on the DataTransfer object.
  return false;
}
function handleDragEnter(e) {
  // this / e.target is the current hover target.
  this.classList.add('over');
}
function handleDragLeave(e) {
    this.classList.remove('over');  // this / e.target is previous target element.
}
function handleDrop(e) {
    // this/e.target is current target element.

    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation(); // Stops some browsers from redirecting.
    }

    // Don't do anything if dropping the same column we're dragging.
    if (dragSrcEl != this) {
        // Set the source column's HTML to the HTML of the column we dropped on.
        dragSrcEl.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
        this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
    }

    return false;
}

function handleDragEnd(e) {
  // this/e.target is the source node.

  [].forEach.call(cols, function (col) {
      col.classList.remove('over');
  });
}
```

If anyone has any experience with this, or any words of wisdom I would be very grateful.

*******Closed************** switched away from Html5 Drag. Its a waste.

Comment: Still need assistance if possible - The solution is probably pretty simple, but I don't think alot of people use HTML5  drag and drop, which is a shame. I find for most uses it is easier than most JS ones.

Comment: You should be able to close your own question.